# How to enable GZIP for Jetty 9

Tags: java, jetty

I'm trying to enabled gzip compression on Jetty 9. I do not want to configure it in my web.xml, so based on the Jetty documentation I've configured a override-web.xml. I'm not using Jetty in an embedded mode, but as a container.

In my `{jetty.home}/webapps` folder, I've my war file - cc.war. I also have defined a cc.xml as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<!-- ==================================================================
Configure and deploy the test web application in $(jetty.home)/webapps/test

Note. If this file did not exist or used a context path other that /test
then the default configuration of jetty.xml would discover the test
webapplication with a WebAppDeployer.  By specifying a context in this
directory, additional configuration may be specified and hot deployments
detected.
===================================================================== -->

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- Required minimal context configuration :                        -->
  <!--  + contextPath                                                  -->
  <!--  + war OR resourceBase                                          -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps"/>/cc.war</Set>

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- Optional context configuration                                  -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<!--   <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
  <Set name="copyWebDir">false</Set>
 -->
    <!--<Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>-->
  <Set name="overrideDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.webapps" default="."/>/cc.d/override-web.xml</Set>
</Configure>
```

In the folder cc.d, I've override-web.xml as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
            <param-value>text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,text/json,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/json,application/xml,application/xml+xhtml,image/svg+xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

Jetty seems to load this fine, but gzip compression is not applied on any of the responses. I say Jetty loaded this fine because earlier when I tried to put the `override-web.xml` in the webapps folder, Jetty was complaining.

I've gone through the various questions here on SO and but none of them seem to have an answer for this.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you wanting a Servlet 2.5 experience on Jetty 9? (just asking, as your override-web.xml declares 2.5, and we don't know what your cc.war is declared as)

Comment: web.xml in my cc.war declares version=2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to configure common filters in [webdefault.xml](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/webdefault-xml.html). Try registering the Gzip filter there.

Comment: webdefault.xml will only be used if it is referenced in a context xml deployable.  It is not used by default on all deployments intentionally.  See [test-jetty-webapp example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.3.v20140905/tests/test-webapps/test-jetty-webapp/src/main/config/demo-base/webapps/test.xml#L29)

Comment: Right you are. But it's still a convenient place to put a filter without touching the war, right?

Comment: it would be best if you copied webdefault.xml to your own copy and modified that one, modifying the in-place webdefault.xml isn't very future proof, and doesn't utilize the ${jetty.base} vs ${jetty.home} features very well.

Comment: @kaqqao It works now!! I had tried setting it in webdefault.xml before but I was not referencing it in my cc.xml. I'm trying out Jetty for the first time as a replacement for tomcat in my current environment and I need to deploy to Jetty as a container. I was not aware that webdefault.xml is not used by default. I will consider embedded deployment in the future.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Any ideas why the override-web.xml did not work? Per the Jetty documentation it says to use override-web.xml.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt The Description in webdefault.xml says the following:                                                  Default web.xml file.  
    This file is applied to a Web application before it's own WEB_INF/web.xml file. Isnt that contradictory to what you are saying?

Comment: @IceMan that description is correct.  IIRC, its webdefault, webapp (WEB-INF/web.xml and associated discovered manifests), then override-web.xml

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Any clues regarding override-web.xml?

Answer (score 2):

One way to keep GZIP configuration out of your application while running in a Jetty container (non-embedded) is to add the filter to your context XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath"><!-- set context path --></Set>
    <Set name="war"><!-- set war path --></Set>

    <Call name="addFilter">
        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</Arg>
        <Arg>/*</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <Call name="of" class="java.util.EnumSet">
                <Arg><Get name="REQUEST" class="javax.servlet.DispatcherType" /></Arg>
            </Call>
        </Arg>
        <Call name="setInitParameter">
            <Arg>mimetypes</Arg>
            <Arg>text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,text/json,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/json,application/xml,application/xml+xhtml,image/svg+xml</Arg>
        </Call>
        <Call name="setInitParameter">
            <Arg>methods</Arg>
            <Arg>GET,POST</Arg>
        </Call>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

Comment: You could also do a similar thing with `jetty-env.xml` (although it might not be the architecturally ideal place): `<Set name="handler"><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.GzipHandler"/></Set>` (for Jetty 8.1; package name might have changed in Jetty 9)